# Proper use or convenience, or both?

Tags: python

In my current project, I am working with a lot of JSON objects that contain arrays, er.. `lists` so I setup a decorator for convienece when the list is one item or multiple. Even though this is convienent in the current project, is it reusable code?

```
def collapse(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        call = function(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(call, (list, tuple)) and (len(call) == 1):
            return call[0]
        return call
    return func

@collapse
def get_results(query, wrapper=None):
    # get json object.
    result = result.json() # using the requests library.
    if wrapper:
        return result[wrapper]
    return result
```

So, `get_results()` has the potential of returning either a `list` or a `dict`. In most cases, the code knows when what type is returned, so using the `@collapse` decorator changes `[result_dict]` to just `result_dict`

Is this a good practice, or should I write a decorator that takes a `limit` parameter

```
@limit(1) # def limit(items=None): ... return data[0:items] if items else data
def get_results(query, wrapper=None):
```

Just wrote out the limit decorator...

```
def limit(items=None, start=0, collapse=False):
    if items and (start > 0):
        items += start
    def wrapper(function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            call = function(*args, **kwargs)
            if isinstance(call, (list, tuple)):
                results = call[start:items] if items else call
                if collapse and (len(results) == 1):
                    return results[0]
                else:
                    return results
            return call
        return func
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

If you expect a list of length 1, raise an exception when that is not the case:

```
if isinstance(call, (list, tuple)) and (len(call) == 1):
    return call[0]
else:
    raise ValueError("List of length 1 expected")
```

A function that may return either a list or an element is hard to use.

Comment: To reinforce this, think of how you would use a function that sometimes returns an object and sometimes returns a list. That would be really messy!